# Get location of a level in a pandas.MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

Given a `pandas.MultiIndex`, I would like to know the level number given a level name.

So, given

```
index = pd.MultiIndex(
        names=['ind1', 'ind2'],
        levels=[['a'], ['b']],
        codes=[[], []]
    )
```

I would like to find out the position of `ind1` and `ind2`, without having to do

```
ind1_loc = [name for name in index.names if name == 'ind1'][0]
```

I feel that definitely should be possible but I can't find it in the documentation.

The reason why I want to do it is because neither `iterrows()` nor `itertuples()` return level names so that you must access the returned index by level number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need indexing if need name of level or `.index` method for position by index name:

```
index = pd.MultiIndex(
        names=['ind1', 'ind2'],
        levels=[['a'], ['b']],
        codes=[[], []]
    )

print (index.names[1])
ind2

print (index.names.index('ind2'))
1
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I was looking for. But I was looking at `pandas.MultiIndex` while I should've been looking at `FrozenList`. Thanks!